# Where is \textthreequartersemdash defined in xelatex/lualatex?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

I cannot find where and how `\textthreequartersemdash` is defined for `xelatex` and `lualtex`. Its definition is absent from TU encoding but `\textthreequartersemdash` prints always dash of same width independently of the font selected. This is demonstrated by the following not very short WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi>0
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={TeX}}
    \newfontfamily{\Cambria}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Cambria}
    \newfontfamily{\Bodoni}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Bodoni MT}
    \newfontfamily{\Stix}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{STIX Two Text}
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\newlength{\len}

\begin{document}

\ifxetex
    This is Xe\LaTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is Lua\LaTeX
\else
    This is pdf\LaTeX
\fi\fi

\bigskip

\textemdash\ \verb|\textemdash| = \settowidth{\len}{\textemdash} \the\len\\
\textthreequartersemdash\ \verb|\textthreequartersemdash| = \settowidth{\len}{{{\textthreequartersemdash}}} \the\len \\
\textendash\ \verb|\textendash| = \settowidth{\len}{\textendash} \the\len \\
\verb|\meaning\textemdash|=\meaning\textemdash\\
\verb|\meaning\textthreequartersemdash|=\meaning\textthreequartersemdash\\

\medskip
{\Bodoni
\textemdash\ \verb|\textemdash| = \settowidth{\len}{\textemdash} \the\len\\
\textthreequartersemdash\ \verb|\textthreequartersemdash| = \settowidth{\len}{{{\textthreequartersemdash}}} \the\len \\
\textendash\ \verb|\textendash| = \settowidth{\len}{\textendash} \the\len \\
\verb|\meaning\textemdash|=\meaning\textemdash\\
\verb|\meaning\textthreequartersemdash|=\meaning\textthreequartersemdash\\
}

\medskip
{\Stix
\textemdash\ \verb|\textemdash| = \settowidth{\len}{\textemdash} \the\len\\
\textthreequartersemdash\ \verb|\textthreequartersemdash| = \settowidth{\len}{{{\textthreequartersemdash}}} \the\len \\
\textendash\ \verb|\textendash| = \settowidth{\len}{\textendash} \the\len \\
\verb|\meaning\textemdash|=\meaning\textemdash\\
\verb|\meaning\textthreequartersemdash|=\meaning\textthreequartersemdash\\
}

\end{document}
```

My guess is that 3/4-emdash is taken from CM fonts but my search in TEX folder of MikTeX tree reveals no reasonable file with definition of `\textthreequartersemdash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in the LaTeX kernel, line 6834 (release 2020-10-01)

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textthreequartersemdash}{\tc@check@symbol{9}\textthreequartersemdash}
```

and comes from the formerly external `textcomp` package.

Using `lualatex` and `\showoutput` we get

```
....\TS1/lmr/m/n/10 ^^V
```

and we can also see, from showing the meaning of the font command,

```
\TS1/lmr/m/n/10=select font ts1-lmr10
```

Thus the glyph is taken from the legacy Type1 font.

There is actually a line

```
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\textthreequartersemdash}{TS1}{22}
```

in the “Unicode” part, but as the status of the symbol is uncertain as far as Unicode is concerned, this is essentially a reminder.

Comment: Such definition of `\textthreequateresemdash` is inconsistent because it prints a dash which has width different from 3/4 of emdash in current TTF font. Wouldn't it be better to define  `\textthreequateresemdash` as `\scalebox{0.75}[1]{\textemdash}`?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov As I said, the symbol has a dubious status (in Unicode, but also generally). You are essentially free to redefine it as you like.